# Vim convert expression to file

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a function which takes the file opened by vim and moves it to a standard directory. My script checks out the name of the current buffer, takes the head of the path of the current file, then transforms it into an expression, stores it in a variable,  and then manipulates the expression so that it becomes the path I want.
Afterwards, I am trying to use `saveas` to save the buffer at a new location.

However, `saveas` receives an argument of type {file}. 
How can I convert an expression to type file?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `execute`:

```
exe 'saveas ' . g:filepath
```

See `h :exe` for details.

Answer (score 2):

Vimscript is evaluated exactly like the Ex commands typed in the `:` command-line. There were no variables in `ex`, so there's no way to specify them. When typing a command interactively, you'd probably use `<C-R>=` to insert variable contents:

```
:sleep <C-R>=timetowait<CR>m<CR>
```

... but in a script, `:execute` must be used. All the literal parts of the Ex command must be quoted (single or double quotes), and then concatenated with the variables:

```
execute 'sleep' timetowait . 'm'
```

#### Escaping

For arguments like filenames, you have to consider that some characters are special (`:help cmdline-special`; e.g. `%` is replaced with the current buffer name), and whitespace should be escaped. Therefore, you need to process your variable through the `fnameescape()` function:

```
:execute 'saveas' fnameescape(g:filepath)
```